# Charges for Google Website Translator

Tags: google-translate

I am thinking to apply Google Translator on my complete website.  Are there any charges for [Google Website Translator](http://translate.google.com/manager/website/suggestions)? And if yes, how will they charge me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the service is free.

> The **free** Website Translator plugin expands your global reach quickly and easily.

[image]

Comment: How do I customize translations for my website? I can't find that option anywhere.